# Reload a module after change

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that a module can be reloaded by issuing:

```
reload(module_name)
```

Suppose that I do not import the whole module but just one function of it.

```
from module_name import one_function
```

How can you reload that specific function when you have made changes to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not reload whole module? Why you want to reload only one function ?

Comment: By the way, when you use `from module_name import one_function` the **whole module** is loaded, just like `import module_name`. The only difference is what names get added to the global namespace.

Comment: Lafada, this raises a NameError.
I haven't explicitly imported the module (i.e import <module name>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to re-import the one name to rebind it; you can reach the cached module object in `sys.modules`:

```
reload(sys.modules['module_name'])
from module_name import one_function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inspect.getmodule` to get the module that owns a function:

```
import inspect
from math import sqrt
from importlib import reload

math = reload(inspect.getmodule(sqrt))
sqrt = math.sqrt
```

---

Using `__qualname__` you can automate this process:

```
def reload_attr(attribute):
    obj = reload(inspect.getmodule(attribute))
    for name in attribute.__qualname__.split("."):
        try:
            obj = getattr(obj, name)
        except NameError:
            raise ValueError("Unable to find attribute.")
    return obj

reload_attr(sqrt)
#>>> <built-in function sqrt>
```

Note that this isn't guaranteed to work; not all attributes are trivial to locate.